# Looping through channel entries with categories

Tags: channel-entries, templates

For a given channel, is it possible to loop through the categories associated with its entries in alphabetical order, then nested-loop through the entries under that category? I'm trying to build a tree-view like template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `category_archive` tag for this unless I've misunderstood your question: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/category_archive.html

Answer (score 1):

Something like this with Stash should do the trick:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news"}
    {categories}
        {exp:stash:append_list name="item_{category_id}"}
            {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
        {/exp:stash:append_list}
    {/categories}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

---

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="news" style="linear"}
    <h2>{category_name}</h2>
    <ul>
        {exp:stash:get_list name="item_{category_id}"}
            <li>{title}</li>
        {/exp:stash:get_list}
    </ul>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```